# Filtering Spark dataframe based on partition URIs that do not follow the standard Spark format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark, for partitioned datasets that don't follow the standard URI format, the Catalyst does not pick up the partitioning information automatically. This means that filters can be highly inefficient. For instance, let's say the partitioning URI format is `/{year}/{month}/{day}` instead of `/year={year}/month={month}/day={day}`.

PySpark solutions that don't involve rewriting the data, registering each partition on the metastore or renaming the directories are appreciated. My guess is that this is possible in Scala?

To make the Catalyst recognize the partitioning structure, a potential solution is to use `F.input_file_name()` to load the partitioning, but this still loads unnecessary partitions instead of filtering. It's easy to test this doesn't work by corrupting a single partition that was not supposed to be read and also specifying the schema.